# Shearing with invariant line

Tags: geometry

What does it mean for a shear to have an invariant line x = 2? Trying to shear a point **(5, 8)** by a factor of 4.

Comment: it probably means all the points on that line are not moved by the sheer.

Comment: Yes I know that they would be moved vertically in this case. But wouldn't it normally be relative to the x-axis or x = 0?

Comment: A shear can go in any direction, examples that you might have been given notwithstanding.

Comment: The wiki page [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) doesn't mention how to change the matrix if the invariant line has a specific value other than just the x-axis.

Comment: Work out the matrix in a coordinate system in which the invariant line *is* a coordinate axis, then transform back. In this case, translate so that the fixed line is the $y$-axis, work out that shear, then translate back. Note that this is *not* a linear transformation, so you can’t represent is with a matrix without using homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: Do you want to put that as the answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widely-applicable method for solving problems like these is to transform to a more convenient coordinate system, apply a simpler operation, then translate back.

In this case, the invariant line is parallel to the $y$-axis. Presumably you know or can work out how to perform a shear parallel to the $y$-axis that leaves the $y$-axis fixed. So, translate $x$ by $-2$ to put this line on the $y$-axis, perform the shear, then translate back.